# Python. Change list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that will figure out a number that the user thinks of.

```
nums=list(range(1,11))

def remove_odd(l):
    return [n for n in l if n % 2 == 0]

y=str(input('Is it an even number?'))
if y=='yes':
    (remove_odd(nums))

print(nums)
```

I get this output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

But I want to get:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not saving the change you have made in the list. Also as a side note: `str(input` is unnecessary as `input` already returns a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not change anything on your list. Change your code to:

```
if y=='yes':
    nums = remove_odd(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nums=list(range(1,11))
def remove_odd(l):
    return [n for n in l if n % 2 == 0]
y=str(input('Is it an even number?'))
if y=='yes':
    nums = remove_odd(nums)
print(nums)
```

You need to use a new variable to receive the return value of the function